# Rails: Datagrid enum filter does not work when multiple or checkboxes options are true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datagrid

I have a form that is using Datagrid for searching on a single table. The filters and searching work as expected, including this one:
`filter(:location, :enum, :select => :locations)`
However, when I try to make that filter show up as checkboxes, like so...
`filter(:location, :enum, :select => :locations, :checkboxes => true)`
...the checkboxes show up but the filter no longer works, and it returns the result set as though I never checked any of the checkboxes at all. This same unexpected behavior also happens when I try to use the `:multiple` option. According to [the Datagrid gem documentation](https://github.com/bogdan/datagrid/wiki/Filters) I don't see any other requirements for making a filter work with checkboxes or multiple select options.

When viewing the requests on my local server, I noticed that the `location` filter is not being added to the SQL query when `:multiple` or `:checkboxes` is set to `true`, but the values ARE being passed in the query string, like so (indicated by FBR and FBZ):
`http://localhost:3000/searches/index?utf8=✓&searches_grid[name]=Foo&searches_grid[location][]=FBR&searches_grid[location][]=FBZ&commit=Search#searchAnchor`
Here's what the working example (no multiples and no checkboxes) looks like:
`http://localhost:3000/searches/index?utf8=✓&searches_grid[name]=Foo&searches_grid[location]=FBR&commit=Search#searchAnchor`

I'm not sure if Datagrid is having trouble rendering parameters that are sent as arrays, or if there's some kind of issue with my versions of Rails/Ruby/etc, or what's going on. If anyone has any suggestions or workarounds I would greatly appreciate them, and if not I will try submitting a Gitlab issue for the gem.

I am using Datagrid 1.5.4, Rails 5.0.3, and Ruby 2.3.1p112.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of dissecting everything in my code, I noticed that the `location` parameters of the `search_params` action in my controller was missing the square brackets to allow it to contain multiple values:

```
    params.require(:searches_grid).permit(
    :name,
    ...more params...
    :order,
    :descending,
    location: [] # <-- Had to add brackets here
  )
```

Now it's working as expected.